# How to transform a generic Animated JS script to work with many classes id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I don't know how I can explain my problem... but I have a Animated JS script and this JS Works fine.

This script identify by CLASS NAME each ICONS on the page marked by the class name - and animated this icons with a delay between each icon.

Then I have in my page 3 sections (all in the same page):

1- About Us 
2- Services
3- Clients

I create this script to use in SERVICES SECTION where I have 20 services, with 20 icons - animated one after other on screen.

But now, I want to use this script in About Us and Clients Sections to animated the icons in this sections

My problem:

The script Works fine for 1 section. If I use in other section I need to wait all animations from the other sections stop to start the animations from the actual sector. (All animations are "scrollbar controlled")

To correct this I clone the script 2x and change the class name for each section.

Problem solved!

But I need to write 3x the same script and only change a class name..

If I need to create another 10 sections, a I will need to write the same script 10x..

There is a way to avoid this?

SORRY! I'M A BEGINNER IN JS.. I understand many things, but I'm not a expert.

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
    var $window = $(window);

    const MULTIPLIER = 800; 
    var countInView = 0; 
    var timeouts = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $animation_elements.length; i++)  
    timeouts[i] = [];

function check_if_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height + 15);

for(var i=0; i < $animation_elements.length ; i++) {
    var $element = $animation_elements.eq(i);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);


if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
    (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {


if($element.is($('i').parent()) && !$element.hasClass('in-view')) {
    var delay = MULTIPLIER * ++countInView;       

    $element.addClass('paused');
    (function(delay, $element, savedtimeout){
      savedtimeout[i][0] = setTimeout(function() {

        $element.removeClass('paused');
        countInView--;
      }, delay);
    }(delay, $element, timeouts));
  }
  $element.addClass('in-view');
} else {


if($element.hasClass('in-view')) {
   $element.removeClass('in-view');
  }

if($element.hasClass('paused')) {
    if(timeouts[i][0] != null) {
      //Retira o timeout da fila
      clearTimeout(timeouts[i][0]);
      countInView--;
    }

    $element.removeClass('paused');
  } // end if
  } // end if
  } // end for
}

    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
    $window.trigger('scroll');
```

Then i change:

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');

var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element2');

var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element3');
```

And copy+paste all the rest

Comment: You can select all elements that have a `class` attribute that starts with the word `animation-element` through *attribute selector*: `var $animation_elements = $('[class^="animation-element"]')`

Comment: hi @dNitro - first of all tks for your precious time! I tried but with this all icons marked with animation-element (I dont change the original class for each icon) disapears on screen (because the animation dont start).

Comment: and this solution - I guess - will alow me to change the class name, but all classes will still working togheter right? my problem is to start the function for each class.

Comment: Could you give a FIDDLE ?!